# What does "Status: Populated, idle" in dmidecode output mean?

Tags: centos, centos7, hp-proliant, central-processing-unit, dmidecode

I have a dual-xeon HP ProLiant DL160 Gen8 server that I'm in the process of setting up, running CentOS 7, and I noticed in my `dmidecode` output that the second processor is listed as `Populated, idle` instead of `Populated, enabled`.  What does it mean?

I've tried putting the system under some load but it still says "idle", even when `top` is showing activity on cores of both processors?

Comment: As per Redhat Solution https://access.redhat.com/solutions/36288  - "Multi core systems displays first of the processor  in dmidecode as Status : Populated, Enabled and the second core will be of Status : Populated, Idle. This is a normal status."